# "Cannot retrieve ENS addresses unless fully synced on main chain" message

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mist, ropsten

I'm deploying a contract in the Ropsten tesnet and even it is deployed correctly (already checked tx in etherscan.io), I can't see it in my Mist Wallet. The command line after deploying the contract says:

"cannot retrieve ENS addresses unless fully synced on main chain"

What does that means? Sounds to me like I have to sync the real chain and not only testnet? I supposed that I wouldn't need to download main blockchain and just test net would be enough.

Comment: You don't need ENS to deploy a contract. What is the address of your contract? What are you trying to see in Mist?

Comment: Sorry probably this question is very basic, but what is ENS?

Comment: [Ethereum Name Service](https://ens.domains/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be synced to the mainnet to interact with your testnet contract.

Could you post the contract 's address in here?

Mist just notified you that ENS is not available when not fully synced, which is correct but not what you are looking for.